# How to print all pages of paginated content in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have generated the data using eloquent and used laravel default pagination 100 record per page in laravel blade view. But, when i print the page it only give me 100 record not all showing all record on print. Is there any function or option for this. [image: Rows shows on print]
[image: Laravel paginated data]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262940/print-all-data-in-multiple-page-pagination

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a specific function, who return a pdf file with all content for print.

It's a better solution.

Comment: Why create a pdf?

Comment: if you need to print all result, create a pdf is a best approach for print.

Comment: I got that, but why? What's the advantage of creating a pdf instead of outputting all results on a HTML page? Why is it "the best approach"?

Comment: If you look a number of page + 100 record per page, 52300 result in one page, this page can be slow. Then create a pdf for print, it's a good solution.

Comment: Still not convinced that creating a 52300 results pdf and downloading it is that faster. Whatever.

Comment: If you create a pdf : you have got more charge into server, if you want render into your navigator : you have got more charge into client. Scroll infinite is a paginator for example, you can't render all data once.